# ArrayList Session 2.0 - Overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, arraylist

What I am trying to do is to keep the value in an array until I clear it out after the `SendEmail()`. Seems that the Session Array is getting overwritten. Any help with be great.

So what I mean is to Add another Record to the ArrayList until I clear it out in the SendEmail() routine.

Of course later I would need to remove the duplicate records in the `ArrayList`.

Here is my C# 2.0 code:

In Login.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyArrayList"] = null;
}
```

In Share.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList idList = new ArrayList();
    idList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));
    Session["MyArrayList"] = idList;                 
}

protected void SendEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // To view the Arraylist
    ArrayList idList = (ArrayList)Session["MyArrayList"];

    foreach (string val in idList) 
    { 
        Response.Write(val); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to actually add stuff to your list each time the page loads your problem is that you're instantiating a new ArrayList each time it loads. So stuff get overwritten instead of being added. Here's what you actually need to do

Login.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyArrayList"] = new ArrayList();
}
```

Share.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ArrayList idList = (ArrayList)Session["MyArrayList"];   
        idList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));
        Session["MyArrayList"] = idList;                 
}
```

In the login page we instantiate the list and store it in the session. In the other page, we get the previously stored list from session and assign it to `idList` and casting it properly, then we add the new stuff to it and return it back to the session.

Note:
This will generate an exception if the session is empty or if it doesn't contain an ArrayList. So you'll probably need to put a checking mechanism in your code.

Comment: What I want it to do is to add on onto that ArrayList.  Not overwrite it.

Comment: Add what to it? When?

Comment: Add another record to the MyArrayList.  So When I call it from SendEmail routine... I would get...   1. Test Record  2. Testing Record   3. Another Record.  Everytime they visit the page.  Then after the SendEmail runs I will clear out that Arraylist.

Comment: On the ArrayList idList = (ArrayList)Session["MyArrayList"]; I am getting this message... [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'.]

Comment: We need to instantiate the list first. See answer now

Comment: Ok Great.  That works now.  Is there a simple way of removing duplicates in that ArrayList?

Comment: Lots of ways. Search SO or ask a separate question for it. And don't forget to accept this answer and rate it up if it has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

First off use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

```
List<string> idList = new List<string>();
idList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));
```

Note: `List<T>` will provide type-safety, so if you try to add anything besides a `string` to the list, then you will get a compilation error.

Second, you only need to update the `Session` value when you first load the page, not on every post back, instead do this:

In Login.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["MyArrayList"] = null;
    }
}
```

In Share.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ArrayList idList = new ArrayList();
        idList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));
        Session["MyArrayList"] = idList;
    }          
}
```